# Incorrect property interpretation of composed Spring Data query

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, datanucleus

I have the following classes

```
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    ...
}

public class Review {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User author;

    @ManyToOne
    private User givenTo;

    ...
}

public interface ReviewRepository extends CrudRepository<Review> {
    Collection<Review> findByGivenToIdAndAuthorId(Long givenToId, Long authorId);
}
```

By invoking `findByGivenToIdAndAuthorId` I get the following error:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Query has DN_THIS.givenTo.author yet author is not found. Fix your input; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Query has DN_THIS.givenTo.author yet author is not found. Fix your input
```

Any idea why?

I also tried with `findByAuthorIdAndGivenToId` but I got the same error with `author.givenTo` instead.

Comment: For me the scenario above creates this query: `select review0_.id as id1_0_, review0_.author_id as author_i2_0_, review0_.given_to_id as given_to3_0_ from review review0_ left outer join user user1_ on review0_.given_to_id=user1_.id left outer join user user2_ on review0_.author_id=user2_.id where user1_.id=? and user2_.id=?` and executes just fine (Hibernate 4.3.10).

Comment: SELECT FROM Review DN_THIS LEFT JOIN DN_THIS.givenTo LEFT JOIN DN_THIS.givenTo.author WHERE ((DN_THIS.givenTo.id = :DN_PARAM_64) AND (DN_THIS.author.id = :DN_PARAM_65))